# AssertionError: cannot transfer value larger than approved amount

Tags: solidity, truffle-test

I have followed the tutorials of Dapp University. Using Ganache and Metamask 127.0.0.1:7545 and did a truffle test or migrate it works perfectly.

Result:
[image]

Then, I change my network this is my `truffle.js`:
[image]

Then, I have geth setup with new `genesis.json`:
[image]

I created 2 accounts. Then started mining. account[0] now has 3000 ethereum, I added in metamask, its shows the same number. Then I added account[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gulyl.png) in metamask with 0 ethereum, works great.

Then I run `truffle migrate --reset --network kennetwork`:
[image]

This is my `DappToken.sol`:
[image]

Then this is my `DappToken.js` the error is happening at line 97:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I get the issue. This seems to work as intended.

If you increase the `approve`d amount (`DappToken.js`, line: 88) from 10 to >= 30, that assertion shouldn't fail anymore.

Comment: omg you did it.. it works! how did you know? have you been studying solidity? i think im gonna really spend full time on understanding solidity but for the mean time ill have to make this token work. thanks a bunch!

Comment: I haven't played with solidity as much as I'd like to, but yes, I studied it a bit. In this case, even the comments suggest what should happen. I remember the concept of `approve`/`transferFrom` was confusing for me too when I learned about it. I'm glad it solved your issue.

Comment: I have a follow up question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/60751/truffle-test-error-deducts-the-amount-from-the-allowance/60752?noredirect=1#comment72971_60752