# Truffle test error: deducts the amount from the allowance

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, truffle-test

What i did first was watching at Dapp university tutorials, I manage to watch all 14 videos and run it with Ganache. But since everything is doing good at local, I created my own private network. Then.. this happens.

When I run `truffle test --reset --network development`

[image]

I think the error is happening in this area `DappToken.js` @ `116`:
[image]

this is my network by the way `truffle.js`:
[image]

Comment: Are you testing with geth? Because I don't think `.then(assert.fail).catch(` will do what you think it does with geth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is on line 88, where the comment above states the test should approve the transfer of 10 tokens, you actually approve 15. This accounts for the test discrepancy of actual: 5 vs expected: 0 in your error.

Comment: i want to increase it from 10 to 30 in order to remove some errors... I eliminated 4 errors out of 5. Now this is the only one.

Comment: You see, you're doing some math, and the last test (on line 116 in your code above) is testing that the final result is 0. If you add 20 to the starting value, you'll need to increase that final check accordingly.